# 「new演算子」や「関数として呼び出す」前の「コンストラクタ内this」はどこに所属？

Tags: javascript

**コンストラクに書いたnewする前のthisは、どこに所属しているのでしょうか？(どこを参照しているのでしょうか？)**
・ただ関数定義しただけでは呼び出せないので、どこにも所属していない？
・もしくは、呼び出し方によって変わるから、それまではどこにも所属できない？

```
function Hoge() {
  this.p = 'テスト';
  console.log(this);
}
```

---

・関数定義した時点で既に、thisはwindow？

```
window.p; //undefined
Hoge.p; //undefined
```

---

・普通に関数呼出しするとthisはwindow

```
   function Hoge() {
      this.p = 'テスト';
      console.log(this);
   }
   Hoge(); //Window
   window.p; //テスト
   this.p; //テスト
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

おっしゃる通り、thisが指す物は呼び出し方によって変わります。
(this は変数ではなくキーワードなので所属、というかスコープのような物は無いと思います)

#### 関数呼び出し

> ・普通に関数呼出しするとthisはwindow

これは strictモードか否かによって変わります。

```
function Hoge(){
    "use strict";
    return this;
}
Hoge();
// -> undefined
```

上記のように strictモードでは this は undefined です。非strictモードではグローバルの this (ブラウザでは window)になります。

#### メソッド呼び出し

```
function Hoge(){
    return this;
}
obj = {a: 1, b: 2, hoge: Hoge};
obj.hoge();
// -> obj
```

他のオブジェクトのメソッドとして呼び出されると、this はその呼び出しに使ったオブジェクトになります

#### `call`や`apply`による呼び出し

```
function Hoge(){
    return this;
}
obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
Hoge.call(obj);
// -> obj
Hoge.apply(obj);
// -> obj
```

call と apply は this のオブジェクトを何にして実行するか指定して、関数を呼び出します。

### new による呼び出し

```
function Hoge(){
    this.p2 = "set in Hoge";
}
Hoge.prototype.p = "set in prototype";
new_obj = new Hoge;
new_obj.p;
// -> "set in prototype"
new_obj.p2;
// -> "set in Hoge"
```

new は 新しいオブジェクトを作ります。
そのオブジェクトのプロトタイプには、与えられた関数オブジェクトの「prototypeプロパティ」が設定されます。
そして、this はその新しいオブジェクトになります。

#### 注意

> ・関数定義した時点で既に、thisはwindow？
>
> window.p; //undefined
>   Hoge.p; //undefined

Hogeのプロパティである`Hoge.p`は Hoge関数の定義内の this.p とは関係ありません。
Hogeにプロパティを追加するには、

```
Hoge.p = 1;
```

のようにします。このように代入しても、もちろん this.p には何の影響もありません。